# Can't get data from col which has datetime format

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to get column data filtered by current time from MS SQL Server. Cells have `datetime` format. But I get empty response. Where is a mistake?

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
$serverName = ''; // server name
$cinfo      = array(
    "Database" => "", // database
    "UID" => "", // user
    "PWD" => "" // pass
);
$conn       = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $cinfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "connected" . "<br/>";
    $datetimenow = current_time("d.m.Y H:i"); // wordpress function
    echo $datetimenow . "<br/>"; // 30.05.2020 14:10
    if (($result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime=$datetimenow")) !== false) {
        while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo $obj->Longitude . '<br />';
        }
    }
} else {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you need some form of quotes round the inserted value in `=$datetimenow"`, better still would be to use prepared statements.

Comment: @NigelRen sorry I am newbie in PHP, how will be correct?

Comment: Try using parameterized queries, aka [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Not only can you avoid having to deal with quoting data, it will help you to avoid issues with [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there are MySQL examples,will  it  work with MS SQL?

Comment: Did you try, management studio, `SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime= <'datetimeNow'>` . Here, the `<'datetimeNow'>` is the value you passed from php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the statement and use parameterized query to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), the *sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

When you use a parameter for `datetime` values, you have two options:

- Pass `datetime` value as text, using unambiguous `datetime` format for the value of `$datetimenow` variable (in your case function `current_time` returns current time as text from formatted PHP datetime object).
- Pass `datetime` value as PHP datetime object using extended parameter syntax.

PHP:

```
<?php
$serverName = '';     // server name
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => "", // database
    "UID" => "",      // user
    "PWD" => ""       // pass
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $cinfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "connected" . "<br/>";

    // Datetime value in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss` format
    $datetimenow = current_time("Y-m-d\TH:i:00");
    // or if you want a specific datetime value
    //$datetimenow = '2020-05-30T14:10:00';

    // Pass datetime value as text
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime = ?";
    $params = array($datetimenow);
    if (($result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params)) !== false) {
        while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo $obj->Longitude . '<br />';
        }
    }

    // Pass datetime value as PHP datetime object
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime = ?";
    $params = array(
        array(
           date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $datetimenow),
           SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, 
           SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_DATETIME, 
           SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME
        )
    );
    if (($result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params)) !== false) {
        while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
            echo $obj->Longitude . '<br />';
        }
    }

} else {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Additional notes:

- When you retrieve data from SQL Server, the `datetime` values are [returned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) as PHP `datetime` objects by default, so you need to use `DateTime->format()` or to set `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string or at the statement level.
- When you send bind values to a decimal or numeric column (also mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15)), *it is recommended to use strings as inputs to ensure precision and accuracy as PHP has limited precision for floating point numbers. The same applies to bigint columns, especially when the values are outside the range of an integer*.

Comment: Why it doesn't work in this case:
```$date1 = '2020-05-30T22:03:00';
                    $date2 = '2020-05-30T22:05:00';
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime >= ? AND <= ?";
                    $params = array($date1, $date2);```
Screenshot of  the table https://imgur.com/a/G8OIB2C

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is wrong. You need to use `"SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE GPS_datetime >= ? AND GPS_datetime <= ?"` or `WHERE GPS_datetime BETWEEN ? AND ?`.

Comment: oh, thank you! And one more question: For example when I try to get rows at 2020-05-30T22:03:00 I get empty response, I think it connects with seconds. In  the original table I don't see seconds what should me do in this case?

Comment: @EugeneChefranov Well, you may try with the something like so: `$date1 = '2020-05-30T22:03:00'; $date2 = '2020-05-30T22:04:00'; $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.GorElectroTrans WHERE ? <= GPS_datetime AND GPS_datetime < ?"; $params = array($date1, $date2);`.

Comment: Yes I also think about this condition but the table shows where are public transport at the moment in the city and the table updates every 1-2 seconds. I think I need to get the table every 2-3 seconds like this ```$date1 = '2020-05-30T22:03:00'; $date2 = '2020-05-30T22:03:03';```